# "A realistic-looking novelty gun" -- meaning of novelty?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/cleveland-crowd-protests-over-boy-shot-police-001423280.html

> Several hundred people marched down an exit ramp and temporarily blocked rush-hour traffic on a busy freeway on Tuesday while protesting a police officer's fatal shooting of a 12-year-old boy who had brandished a realistic-looking **novelty gun**.

How should I understand **novelty gun**?

Comment: How do you think you should, or might? It's in the dictionary...

Comment: GR. *[novelty](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/novelty_1): 3 [countable] a small cheap object sold as a toy or a decorative object* (OALD)

Comment: @CarSmack Which is why I voted to close, as should you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Novelty' can mean an inexpensive toy. It's often used to describe toys that are meant to play a joke or are gimmicky - like fake noses and glasses or funny post-it notes.